# How can I fix the "Couldn't create file parser context for file ..." bug with Perl libxml on Debian?

Tags: perl, debian, libxml2

When I try to read an XML file with [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple), sometimes I get this error message:

> Couldn't create file parser context for file ...

After some googling, it seems to be [a problem with libxml-libxml-perl](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=240334) and is supposed to be fixed in the version I use (1.59-2).

Any ideas?

Edit: (code)

```
sub Read
{
  my ($file, $no_option) = @_;
  my %XML_INPUT_OPTIONS = ( KeyAttr => [], ForceArray => 1 );

  if ((defined $file) && (-f $file))
  {
    my @stats = stat($file);
    if ((defined $XML_CACHE{$file})
      && ($stats[9] == $XML_CACHE{$file}{modif_time}))
    {
      return ($XML_CACHE{$file}{xml});
    }
    else
    {
      my $xml = eval { XMLin($file,
        (defined $no_option ? () : %XML_INPUT_OPTIONS)) };
      AAT::Syslog("AAT::XML", "XML_READ_ERROR", $@) if ($@);
      $XML_CACHE{$file}{modif_time} = $stats[9];
      $XML_CACHE{$file}{xml} = $xml;
      return ($xml);
    }
  }

  return (undef);
}
```

And yes, I should & will use [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple) cache feature...

Comment: I just did, sorry for the delay...

Answer (score 1):

Does the error continue "No such file or directory at..."? If so, then I think that the problem is that (for whatever reason) when you get to that point in the script, whatever you are passing to `XML::Simple` has no xml file in it. Long story short, the script you are using may be passing a bad variable (blank? empty?) to `XML::Simple` at which point the module chokes. To debug, add a check on whatever you hand to `XML::Simple` before you pass it along. (See the next paragraph for a concrete example explaining *why* I think this may be your problem.)

A few months ago, I had a similar problem with [`Weather::Google`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Weather::Google). In a nutshell, the weather module was trying to get data from Google via `LWP::Simple` *without a user agent*. Google began (apparently) to reject requests without a user agent. I had to backtrack through the modules because the error appeared to come from `XML::Simple`. In fact, it was caused by what was done in `LWP::Simple` and `Weather::Google`. Or rather, the error was a result of `Weather::Google` not checking the data that was in an object created via `LWP::Simple`. In a case like this, it can be hard at first to see what's going wrong and where.

Comment: Yes, there is "No such file or directory at..." after, but I check that this file exists before XMLin (-f $file)